# Use Windows CMD findstr to match lines with two words separated by one or more spaces

Tags: cmd, findstr

For the file sub.txt

```
callfoo()     # no match
call_foo()    # no match
call foo()    # match
call  foo()   # match
```

the command

```
findstr call.*foo sub.txt
```

matches all lines. How can I match the last two lines, where "call" and "foo" are separated by one or more spaces and no other characters? Trying to use regular expressions with

```
findstr /R call\s.*foo sub.txt
```

does not match anything.

Comment: Type `findstr /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help text…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findstr /RC:"call  *foo" sub.txt
```

find `call` followed by a space, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by `foo`.

The usage of the `/c` switch is essential to process the spaces as characters and not as separators.

`\s` is not part of the crippled `findstr` REGEX.

Comment: Your command matches "call" followed by *one* or more spaces, not zero or more. So it does not match "calfoo". It does what I wanted. Please edit your message if I am right.

Comment: as per your question: `where "call" and "foo" are separated by one or more spaces and no other characters`. My answer is `followed by a space, followed by zero or more spaces`,  which is effective "one or more spaces". `Findstr` has no "one or more", so we need "one plus (zero or more)".